# custom view/template for custom exception

Tags: django

In my views I am using some module which connects to external api.
I want this module to throw some custom exception like for example `ApiServerNotRespond`.
Then I want this exception to cause custom view/template to be rendered. For example if in my view "connect_to_api" (where I am using my api module) api module will cause `ApiServerNotRespond` exception then for example `not_respond` view is called instead or just `myapp/not_respomd.html` template rendered.

I don't want to use any middleware things because I want all config reside in my app dir not in settings file.

Where and how I can define custom exception and how to force it to render custom template after it is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by writing a decorator.

The decorator should catch `ApiServerNotRespond` or any other exception you want. And if such exception occurs return response with template you want otherwise just return response from the original view.

Sample:

```
def custom_error_handler():
    def decorator(orig_func):
        def inner_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return orig_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            except ApiServerNotRespond:
                context = {}
                return render_to_response('custom_template.html', context
                         context_instance = RequestContext(request))
            except Exception:
                #handle all other errors, may be just raise
                raise 
       return wraps(orig_func)(inner_func)
    return decorator
```

In your views.py,

```
@custom_error_handler
def sample_view1(request):
    #your code
```

Comment: It looks nice but where I put code of custom_error_handler()? In which file?

Comment: @user606521, `decorators.py` in your app folder will be good. If you want to use it in multiple apps, may be you can create common module and put in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do proper exceptions, but then you'd need to wrap calls to module's functions in something similar to `get_object_or_404()` so each time an exception happens, you practically redirect to the error page. Also, all calls to the service would need to be wrapped...

Another approach would be to use a decorator for your view(s) dealing with the service. Then, an api function call would raise the exception and the decorator would catch it and render the appropriate page (like the `login_required` decorator). -- I'd pick this one, is more elegant :)

Either way, you'd probably need to provide some sort of wrapper calls to the service so it literally throws the exceptions.